# flutter Got socket error trying to find package android_alarm_manager: ^0.1.0

Tags: dart, flutter

I just tried to get package  from `pubspec.yaml` (with `flutter packages get` command) in my Flutter project but it raised this error :

> Got socket error trying to find package android_alarm_manager: ^0.1.0"

I'm working on my company computer (Windows 7) that is behind proxy but I absolutely have no problem for other packages (ex. font_awesome_flutter: 6.0.0).

I tried with flutter beta version.

pubspec.yaml

```
name: background
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  font_awesome_flutter: 6.0.0
  android_alarm_manager: ^0.1.0
  isolate: ^2.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score -1):

remove the proxy you are using first then get the package again

Comment: This is concidered a comment.